# LookupFieldEditor.ascx in SharePoint 2007/2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, moss, sharepoint-2010, lookup

I have searched for LookupFieldEditor example but I could not find any sample code or markup using this control. I want to know how should I use it in a web page in my SharePoint site.

Answer (score 0):

You can see this control in action on every Display or Edit form of a List that has a Lookup field. In the 12 or 14 hive, take a look at TEMPLATE\XML\FLDTYPES.XML. For SharePoint 2007, the LookupFieldEditor reference is on line 422 as a part of the Lookup field type.

I would not recommend using LookupFieldEditor.ascx directly on a web page. However, you could use it as a part of (or as inspiration for) your own custom field type.